# Firebase Dynamic Links Opening all of my domain links in the app

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using a custom domain for Firebase Dynamic Links in my Unity app. The domain is in the format `https://mywebsite.com/deeplink/`

On Android, this all works fine. Going to `mywebsite.com` by clicking a link in an email or the browser, opens the URL in the browser and `mywebsite.com/deeplink` opens the app. On iOS, however, **both** open the app. This includes, most troubling, the `mywebsite.com/_/` URL which Firebase uses for its confirm your email and reset password logic.

My app is configured with `applinks:mywebsite.com` in the associated domains section and the PList has an entry for `FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains` with an array that has `https://mywebsite.com/deeplink` as an entry.

`mywebsite.com/apple-site-association` has this

```
{"applinks":{"apps":[],"details":[{"appID":"LK3H8YP4D2.com.help.stressfree","paths":["NOT /_/*","/*"]}]}}
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening and how I can get the app to only open URLs at mywebsite.com/deeplink?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Even after uninstalling the app, deleting, the app, installing the app, still all paths to dynamic link domain opens the app.

Comment: @coolcool1994 Did you found any solution to restrict any url not to open in iOS app?

Comment: I'm sure we worked around it somehow but it was 2 years ago now and I've long since left that company so I'm afraid I can't be more helpfu.

Answer (score -1):

The root domain of your custom Dynamic Link `mywebsite.com` shouldn't be added in the Associated Domains list. That's the reason why `mywebsite.com` opens the app in iOS.

Only Google-provided domains (*.page.link) should be added in the Associated Domains list.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive#open-dynamic-links-in-your-app

Comment: Really? That's not at all clear by the example `applinks:your_dynamic_links_domain`

Comment: It's explained in items 2 and 3 of the link I've shared. You can file a ticket to Firebase Support to share your feedback https://firebase.google.com/support

Comment: It does, but it implies you do both, not either-or. Thanks for the advice though. I will give it a try next week.

Comment: This doesn't work. Removing this, the links open in the App Store

Comment: Yeah this answer doesn't work. When you remove the custom dynamic link domain from associated domains list, the dynamic links stop working in that  dynamic links no longer open the app and they open the App Store. -1